# C++ char pointer to char variable

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm given a method header as so:

```
char* thisMethod(char* input){}
```

is it possible to say,

```
char var = input[0];
```

? I know that "input" will be in the form of a char array.

I'm obviously new to C++ pointers are throwing me off. I tried researching how to work with char pointer function arguments but couldn't find anything specific enough to help. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is that second line of code intended to go inside the function? If so, write it that way. And, yes, if you do that, it will copy the character that `input` points to into `var`.

Comment: Picking at nits, all you can guarantee is that there is one character that the pointer is pointing to.  Anything else is an assumption.  For passing more than one character, use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` or some other container.

Answer (score 1):

There is a misconception that may lead you into further troubles:

> I know that "input" will be in the form of a char array.

**NOPE:** By the scope of that function, `input` is a **pointer to a character**.  The function has no way to know where such a pointer comes from.

If it has been taken from an array upon calling the function than it will be a `pointer to the first element of that array`.

Because pointer have an arithmetic that allows to add offsets and because the `[]` operator applied to pointers translates as `a[b] = *(a+b)` by definition, in whatever code, if a is `a` pointer, `*a` and `a[0]` are perfect synonymous.

Think to an array as a sequence of *boxes* and a pointer as *your hand's index finger*

adding an offset to a *finger* (like `finger+2`) means "*re-point it aside*" and de-referencing it (like `*finger`) means "look inside what it *points to*".

The [] operator on pointers is just a shortcut to do both operations at once.

Arrays are another distinct thing. Don't think to them when dealing with pointers, since -in more complex situations, like multidimensional array or multi-indirection pointers - the expression a[b][c] won't work anymore the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's inside the function and `input` points to something valid ( not `NULL`/`nullptr` and not a garbage location ) then doing `char var = input[0];` is just fine. It's the same as `char var = *input`.

P.S If it's supposed to be a string I recommend using `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get a value from a pointer, `*` and `[]`. The following are equivalent:

```
char var1 = *input;
char var2 = input[0];
```

Using the brackets is more common when you know you were passed an array, since it allows you to supply an index. You need some way of knowing where the end of the array is so that you don't attempt any access past it, your function is missing that important detail.

Comment: Now would it be ok to use input[1] input[2] etc to continue down the char array that I know is being looked at by the pointer? Or is there a way to place the char array into a string so it is easier to track the size/boundaries of the char[]/string?

Comment: @BrandonWalker The usual convention with strings is for every character to be valid until you reach a character with a value of zero. Not `'0'`, but `0`. If you have that you can easily copy it to a `std::string` with simple assignment.